# How to use pygame to detect the pressed button from two seperate functions with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

In the `main()` function, I started a pygame window and the threadings. The threadings are 2 functions `event1()` and `event2()`. This is my code:

```
import threading
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def event1():
   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN: 
                key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
                if key_input[pygame.K_UP] :
                print("from event 1")



def event2():
   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN: 
                key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
                if key_input[pygame.K_UP] :
                print("from event 2")


def main():

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))

    thread_event1 = threading.Thread(target=event1)
    thread_event2 = threading.Thread(target=event2)
    thread_event1.daemon = True
    thread_event2.daemon = True
    thread_event1.start()
    thread_event2.start()

main()
```

When I press the key up my code is supposed to give (Since the two functions are being executed at the same time) :

```
from event1
from event2
```

but I got this result:

```
from event1
```

and sometimes I get:

```
from event2
```

am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: `pygame.event.get()` clears the event buffer. Meaning, one thread will clear it before the other one has the chance to get the lock on the event pool. If i'm not mistake, Pygame has a lock on `pygame.event.get()` calls.

Comment: What is the code trying to achieve by using the threads?  Typically with event-driven GUIs only *one* thread handles events.  If there needs to be threads doing work in the background, they interact with the GUI thread by posting events.